# Blazor: Getting the EF application user all the way to my sub component

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, blazor

I've got a pretty basic application built just for some experimentation and self-improvement. I've got an SQL-database with a few tables. Now, I have created some tables which I want to save who has created or modified a record.

To make it simple I just save the applicationUser to these tables through a call similar to this:

```
async Task HandleSubmit()
{
    newMessage.CreatedBy = user;
    newMessage.Created = DateTime.Now;
    newMessage.CharacterName = user.CharacterName;

    await chatService.AddChatMessage(newMessage);
    chats = await chatService.GetAllChats();
}
```

This is done in the standard Home.razor file that gets created by default.

Now my problem is... I've gone a little overboard where I want to write to another table from another component that is pretty heavily nested:

The main parent which has an ApplicationUser contains the following:

```
    <CascadingAuthenticationState>
        <AreasTable areas="areas" />
    </CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

Which points to:

```
<table class="ui inverted very basic table">
    <tbody>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Created</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        @foreach (var area in areas)
        {
            <AreasRow area=area />
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public List<Area> areas { get; set; }
}
```

Which in turn points to:

```
<tr>
    <td><span class="ui small text">@area.Name</span></td>
    <td><span class="ui small text">@area.Created</span></td>
    <td><EditAreaButton areaId="area.Id" /></td>
</tr>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public Area area { get; set; }
}
```

Which finally points to:

```
<button class="ui btn-primary" @onclick="@ViewArea">Edit</button>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public Guid areaId { get; set; }

    void ViewArea()
    {
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo($"/speedwalks/view/{areaId}");
    }
}
```

This in turn points the user to the speedwalks-site. And from there I really can't figure out how I'm supposed to reach the ApplicationUser to enable me to write the ModifiedBy and CreatedBy parameters.

As you can see I have tried the CascadingAuthenticationState, but I'm not sure I fully understand how it is supposed to be used.
I have tried with the AuthenticationStateProvider, but that only returns a ClaimsPrincipal.
I have tried sending the user as a parameter through all the components, but as the last component is both a regular html-element and also a NavigationManager handles the traffic, I'm thinking my user can't "get through".

How SHOULD I do with my ApplicationUser in this case?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.getuserasync?view=aspnetcore-8.0

Comment: Sounds like you should inject the Authentication state into the /speedwalks/view/{areaId} page

Comment: Is that what you SHOULD do? Inject the authentication state into all pages that require it? You can't just pass the user around?